# Shopify Graphql how to get available products for specific collection based on location

Tags: graphql, shopify, shopify-api

Shopify GraphQL. I want to have a list of products for specific collection based on location.

Expectrd list of products.
I tried:

```
query($collectionId: ID!, $locationId: ID!) {
  collection(id: $collectionId) {
    products(first: 50) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          title
          availableForSale
          images(first: 50) {
            edges {
              node {
                id
                altText
                originalSrc
              }
            }
          }
          variants(first: 50, query: "location_id:$locationId") {
            edges {
              node {
                id
                title
                inventoryQuantity
                sku
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I have an error for variants not support query

Answer (score -1):

It is true. Variants do not in fact have a location. But they do have an inventory item ID. And when you leverage that, you'll find you can get the inventory levels of any particular inventory item ID at locations.

So if you were to extract the availability of an item at a location, ie) a variant, you would also know that the product the variant belongs to, is stocked at that location.

Your approach of starting with a collection, and then getting the products in that collection, and then getting the variants of each product, and then checking if the variant is stocked at one or more locations, is really really clunky.

I think instead you should extract the inventory at each location. That would then give you products. With those products you might be able to create a collection to hold them. But since location is not a criteria, you're going to have to make up something.